# Why can I only invoke sys.stdin with a for loop

Tags: python, sys

it seems like I can only invoke it by using a for loop

```
for line in sys.stdin:
     print line
```

where can I find documentations on how sys methods are structured
I've looked at the official documentation and that really wasn't enough

thanks

Comment: Seriously, can't you just google that documentation? Here is the link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.stdin

Comment: sorry, forgot to add that I've already saw this one... that really isn't enough for a python beginner @mu無

Comment: What do you mean by "invoke it"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stdin is a pipe. It has methods such as read and readline.

```
help(sys.stdin)
```

Tells you what you need to know.